# 3D animation in PageView/Carousel/Slider in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, slider, carousel, flutter-pageview

I have a pageView builder, and want to have a 3D type animation more like a hexagon.
[image]

Presently I just have a simplePageView builder and I just know we have to use `transform` or `matrix4`, but ran short of sources to completely grasp the concepts behind

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<DesktopLayout> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;
  List<String> items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> itemList = items
        .map((item) => Container(
              height: 200,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              color: selectedIndex == items.indexOf(item)
                  ? Colors.blueAccent
                  : Colors.blueGrey,
              child: Text(
                item,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ))
        .toList();

    PageController controller =
        PageController(initialPage: selectedIndex, viewportFraction: 0.4);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 60,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedIndex = index;
                      controller.animateToPage(selectedIndex,
                          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                          curve: Curves.easeInOut);
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: selectedIndex == index
                          ? Colors.blueAccent
                          : Colors.grey[300],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        items[index],
                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 150,
                child: PageView(
                  controller: controller,
                  children: itemList,
                  onPageChanged: (index) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedIndex = index;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

I am even open for any other methods like `carousel_slider` to get the desired work done.